Explore automatic paging
I'm exploring how to be able to auto-paginate.
I use tikz,
\ExplSyntaxOn

\definecolor{tocline}{RGB}{57, 77, 5}
\cs_set:Npn \ljguo_tocline_box:nn #1#2
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every~node/.style={inner~sep = 0pt, outer~sep = 0pt}]
    \node[align = center, font = \LARGE\bfseries, text = tocline, rotate = 90] (chapter) at (0, 0) {#1};
    \node[anchor = west] (section) at (1.5, 0) {\parbox{\dim_eval:n {\textwidth - 2.5cm}}{#2}};
    \draw[thick] ([xshift = -(1.5cm - .5em)/2, yshift = -1em]section.south~west) -- ([xshift = -(1.5cm - .5em)/2, yshift = 1em]section.north~west);
    \draw[thick] ([xshift = -(1.5cm - .5em)/2 - 0.2cm, yshift = -1em - 0.2cm]section.south~west) rectangle ++ (.4, .2);
    \draw[thick] ([xshift = -(1.5cm - .5em)/2 - 0.2cm, yshift = 1em + 0.2cm]section.north~west) rectangle ++ (.4, -.2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\lipsum[1-3] \\[1cm]

\vspace*{3cm}

\ljguo_tocline_box:nn{\LaTeXe}
{
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

this will get,

everything is normal.
When I try to add content,
\ljguo_tocline_box:nn{\LaTeXe}
{
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After
}


the effect I hope to achieve is
\ljguo_tocline_box:nn{\LaTeXe}
{
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After
}

\\

\ljguo_tocline_box:nn{\LaTeXe}
{
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After
}


MWE:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{showframe}


\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\definecolor{tocline}{RGB}{57, 77, 5}
\cs_set:Npn \ljguo_tocline_box:nn #1#2
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every~node/.style={inner~sep = 0pt, outer~sep = 0pt}]
    \node[align = center, font = \LARGE\bfseries, text = tocline, rotate = 90] (chapter) at (0, 0) {#1};
    \node[anchor = west] (section) at (1.5, 0) {\parbox{\dim_eval:n {\textwidth - 2.5cm}}{#2}};
    \draw[thick] ([xshift = -(1.5cm - .5em)/2, yshift = -1em]section.south~west) -- ([xshift = -(1.5cm - .5em)/2, yshift = 1em]section.north~west);
    \draw[thick] ([xshift = -(1.5cm - .5em)/2 - 0.2cm, yshift = -1em - 0.2cm]section.south~west) rectangle ++ (.4, .2);
    \draw[thick] ([xshift = -(1.5cm - .5em)/2 - 0.2cm, yshift = 1em + 0.2cm]section.north~west) rectangle ++ (.4, -.2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\lipsum[1-3] \\[1cm]

\vspace*{3cm}

\ljguo_tocline_box:nn{\LaTeXe}
{
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After\\
    Before~\dotfill\ After
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}

Maybe it's not for paging, but if the current page cannot fit, it will be automatically split into two \ljguo_tocline_box:nn.

longtable (and I think tcolorbox,) doesn't implement any page breaking algorithm, it just exposes each row as a line such that tex's normal page breaker sees it as a separate line, like a line of a paragraph. that is why longtable can not break within a row and why you can't break within a  tikz picture,

You can use tcolorbox to add a custom decoration on the left side of the box. Or set your lines as normal text and then use tikzmarks to add the decorations afterwards, e.g. https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2076#a2309

You could theoretically make it a forest tree and enable automatic breaking. I wouldn't recommend it, though. (And it is not something forest can do out-of-the-box.)

Maybe it's not for paging, but if the current page cannot fit, it will be automatically split into two \ljguo_tocline_box:nn

you have to implement it differently if you want it to split. you can't split a tikzpicture - let alone a node.

Or put another way, can you get the remaining height of the current page? Choose to split at the right place.

I seem to have found a solution...
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{showframe}


\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\definecolor{tocline}{RGB}{57, 77, 5}

\dim_new:N \g__current_page_remaining_height_dim
\dim_new:N \g__tocline_box_content_height_dim
\box_new:N \g__tocline_content_box


\seq_new:N \g__tocline_content_left_seq 
\seq_new:N \g__tocline_content_right_seq 
\int_new:N \g__tocline_content_int 


\cs_set:Npn \ljguo_tocline_aux_box:nn #1#2
{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every~node/.style={inner~sep = 0pt, outer~sep = 0pt}]
    \node[align = center, font = \LARGE\bfseries, text = tocline, rotate = 90] (chapter) at (0, 0) {#1};
    \node[anchor = west] (section) at (1.5, 0) {\parbox{\dim_eval:n {\textwidth - 2.5cm}}{#2}};
    \draw[thick] ([xshift = -(1.5cm - .5em)/2, yshift = -1em]section.south~west) -- ([xshift = -(1.5cm - .5em)/2, yshift = 1em]section.north~west);
    \draw[thick] ([xshift = -(1.5cm - .5em)/2 - 0.2cm, yshift = -1em - 0.2cm]section.south~west) rectangle ++ (.4, .2);
    \draw[thick] ([xshift = -(1.5cm - .5em)/2 - 0.2cm, yshift = 1em + 0.2cm]section.north~west) rectangle ++ (.4, -.2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\cs_new:Npn \__ljguo_seq_split_from_index:NnNN #1#2#3#4 
{
  \seq_clear:N #3
  \seq_clear:N #4
  \int_step_inline:nnn { 1 } { #2 }
  {
    \seq_put_right:Ne #3 { \seq_item:Nn #1 { ##1 } }
  }
  \int_step_inline:nnn { #2 + 1 } { \seq_count:N #1 }
  {
    \seq_put_right:Ne #4 { \seq_item:Nn #1 { ##1 } }
  }
}


\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__ljguo_seq_split_from_index:NnNN { NoNN }

\cs_set:Npn \ljguo_tocline_box:nn #1#2 
{
  \null
  \dim_set:Nn \g__current_page_remaining_height_dim { \dim_eval:n {\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip} }
  \vbox_set:Nn \g__tocline_content_box { #2 }
  \dim_set:Nn \g__tocline_box_content_height_dim { \box_ht:N \g__tocline_content_box + 2em + 0.4cm}

  \dim_compare:nTF { \g__current_page_remaining_height_dim > \g__tocline_box_content_height_dim }
  {
    \ljguo_tocline_aux_box:ne { #1 }{ #2 }
  }
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \g__tocline_content_seq { \\ }{ #2 }
    
    \__ljguo_seq_split_from_index:NoNN \g__tocline_content_seq 
    {
      \int_eval:n { \g__current_page_remaining_height_dim / \baselineskip - 3 }
    }
    \g__tocline_content_left_seq
    \g__tocline_content_right_seq
    
    \ljguo_tocline_aux_box:ne { #1 } 
    {
      \seq_use:Nn \g__tocline_content_left_seq { \\ }
    }
    \clearpage
    \ljguo_tocline_box:ne { #1 }
    {
      \seq_use:Nn \g__tocline_content_right_seq { \\ }
    }
  }
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \ljguo_tocline_box:nn { ne }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \ljguo_tocline_aux_box:nn { ne }

\lipsum[1-3] 

\par 

\ljguo_tocline_box:nn{\LaTeXe}
{
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After\\
  Before~\dotfill\ After
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}


